# how to optimize the media-query styles

Tags: css, media-queries

I am repearting the styles in my media-query test but don't know how to optimize the sytles without repeating the same styles.

here is my sample styles

```
@media screen and  (min-width: 1261px) and  (max-width: 1340px)  { 
    .wishlist-wrap {width:24.5245901639%}
    .info-wrap {width:24.262295081%}
    .meta-menu-wrap {width:28.86885245%}
    .nav-head > ul > li {padding-right:1.8823529411%;}
}

@media screen and  (min-width: 1211px) and  (max-width: 1260px)  { 
    .wishlist-wrap {width:20.5245901639%}
    .info-wrap {width:25.262295081%}
    .nav-head > ul > li {padding-right:2.8823529411%;}
    .meta-menu-wrap {width:30.86885245%}
}

@media screen and  (min-width: 1181px) and  (max-width: 1210px)  { 
    .wishlist-wrap {width:20.5245901639%}
    .info-wrap {width:26.262295081%}
    .nav-head > ul > li {padding-right:2.8823529411%;}
    .meta-menu-wrap {width:30.86885245%}
}

@media screen and  (min-width: 1080px) and  (max-width: 1180px)  { 
    .wishlist-wrap {width:20.5245901639%}
    .info-wrap {width:28.262295081%}
    .logo-wrap {width:14.68852459%;}
    .meta-menu-wrap {width:30.86885245%}
    .nav-head > ul > li {padding-right:2.0823529411%;font-size:13px}
    .panel-primary { padding: 6px 36px 10px 20px;}
}
```

Comment: hhmmmm..... All good. But bootstrap better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set it up like so

CSS

```
normal css

media querys (use max-width only, don't limit it to a min - max) {
    // override what you need to only
}
media querys {
    // override what you need to only
}
```

for example you have

```
.meta-menu-wrap {width:30.86885245%}
```

repeated a few times, if you just defined this at a max-width of xxx and not limit it to a range, then you would not need to define it again for smaller screens until you need to change it again

```
.meta-menu-wrap { width:28.86885245% }

@media screen and (max-width: 1260px)  { 
    .meta-menu-wrap { width:30.86885245% }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1210px)  { 
    // no need to do it again here
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1180px)  { 
    // no need to do it here
}
```

Also your percents are quite precise however the actual calculated pixels will differ from browser to browser. Nothing wrong with it but just a note.

Answer (score 1):

As Huangism said you should provide the base style outside the @media-querys and online override the necessary styles in them.

Besides that you could take a look at http://lesscss.org/ or http://sass-lang.com/ they both allow to define variables and function-like elements and allow to use mathematic formula to calculate sizes. This helps to structure your css and is pretty easy to learn.

short less example:

```
.insertWidths(@size){
   .wishlist-wrap { width: **formula_dependent_on_size** }
   .info-wrap { ... }
   .nav-head > ul > li { ... }
   .meta-menu-wrap { ... }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1260px)  { 
   .insertWidths(1260);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1210px)  { 
    .inserWidths(1210);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1180px)  { 
    .inserWidths(1180)
}
```

Hope that helps, best regards
Ludwig